# Is it possible to add margin-bottom to expand the size of the body?

Tags: css

I have a `div` with colored background and a footer that is absolute positioned at the bottom of the page. I'm trying to add margin-bottom to the div in order to add some space between the div and the footer. But it doesn't have any effect. I assume this is because margin is relative to another element. What is a good solution in this scenario?

```
<body> <!--white background-->
  <div> <!--colored background-->
   <!--THe content of the page -->
  </div>
  <footer>
   "links"
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: https://trunk.zenconomy.se/köp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you need is a "Sticky Footer", search S.O or Google for it, you don't want to solve something that's been solved a 100 times already :-). Since the footer is absolutely positioned, adding a margin to it or the content div won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display:block.

Or if that doesn't work try using padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom.

One of these should work!

Edit: Sorry, if you set the bottom padding/margin of the DIV to the height of the footer, PLUS the height of the gap you're trying to achieve, it should work. The absolutely positioned footer won't be pushed anywhere by the div because it's taken out of the page flow when you set it to absolute.

Comment: The div is already a block and I can't use padding because of the background color.